# Help to understand these statements

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to understand this paragraph in a real analysis book:

> Let $f:U\to \mathbb R$ be defined in an open set $U\subset \mathbb
>  R^n$. Since $U$ is open, there exists $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that
>   $-\epsilon \lt t\lt \epsilon\implies \lambda(t)=a+te_i\in U$ . The
>   partial derivative of $f$ at a point $a$ is the derivative, at the
>   point $t=0$, of the function
>   $f\circ\lambda:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to\mathbb R$, i.e.,
>   $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a)=(f\circ\lambda)'(0)$.

I didn't understand why $-\epsilon \lt t\lt \epsilon\implies \lambda(t)=a+te_i\in U$ and why $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a)=(f\circ\lambda)'(0)$.

Thanks

Comment: Because the set $U$ is open, so there is an ball of radius $\epsilon$  centered at $a$ contained in $U$.

Comment: What he's trying to do is start at a point $a\in U$ and move in a straight line in one of the standard directions, but he wants to make sure he stays inside $U$ so that the function is defined.

Comment: He's ultimately trying to say that a partial derivative is the same as just moving in a line in one of the standard directions and taking the one-dimensional derivative.  He's trying to give you intuition  about the meaning of the partial derivative.

Comment: @WillJagy He didn't really use the chain rule, he's just equating the partial derivative with the derivative of a composition of functions.  The chain rule would say $(f\circ\lambda)'(0)=f'(\lambda(0))\lambda'(0)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists an open ball $B(a,\epsilon)\subset U$. Then,

$$-\epsilon<t<\epsilon\implies \|a-(a+te_i)\|=|t|\|e_i\|<\epsilon$$

and

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+te_i)-f(a)}t=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(\lambda(t))-f(\lambda(0))}t=(f\circ\lambda)'(0)$$